# How do I set up Play Framework 2.0 in Netbeans with Scala IDE

Tags: scala, netbeans, playframework-2.0

I downloaded the http://wiki.netbeans.org/Scala "Scala IDE" Netbeans Plugin, and it works great. I then created a new Scala project from existing sources. Also worked great. The only issue is now that Netbeans does not recognize any of the play classes/packages. It seems that the SBT plugin somehow automatically downloads dependencies. How can I download these dependencies manually, and add them to my Netbeans library, or where can I find the downloaded Play JAR's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried this myself but perhaps you can run `play eclipsify` and then do a File->Import Project->Eclipse Project from Netbeans.